# Batch Syncing between two system and one system reverted its state to older DB state. Syncing Problem

Tags: enterprise-architecture, architectural-patterns, application-design, reporting

We have a system which generates db records and a ever increasing id named archive_id ( bigint in postgres).

sample table: record_table ------ archive_id bigint,info varchar

Another system continuously polls the first system DB and get records in its system based on archive_id column.

When first system DB is restored to some older version for some issue. Syncing stops between first system and second system.

Eg:

First System records in record_table are:

archive_id   info

```
1         info-1

2         info-2

3         info-3
```

second system synced to

archive_id   info

```
1         info-1

2         info-2

3         info-3
```

Now when first system is restored to older version till 2 like and generates a new 3 info value:

archive_id   info

```
1         info-1

2         info-2

3         NEW_INFO_3
```

Now as the second system DB already has archive_id 3 it dosent sync the new value. Any solutions for this problem.